# How to join three mysql tables and select rows for given attribute (customerNumber)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to write a MySQL query that achieves the following:

*Based on the selected customerNumber it should show all the
products the customer ordered with all the product details and order details in a chronological order based on the order date.*

The ERD looks like this:
[image: ERD]

For each selected cusomterNumber I only need the data from the order, orderdetails and product tables.

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this AND CHANGE WHAT YOU NEED to make it works.

So each `*` must be replace by the list of the column of the table you want to display :

```
SELECT 
    C.customerNumber ,  -- the customer id
    O.*,                -- replace by O.column_name1, O.column_name2, ...
    OD.*,               -- replace by OD.column_name1, OD.column_name2, ...
    P.*                 -- replace by P.column_name1, P.column_name2, ...
FROM customers as C
-- If you only want customer with at least ONE orders, change LEFT JOIN by INNER JOIN
LEFT JOIN orders as O on O.customerNumber = C.customerNumber
-- I suppose orderLineNumber is the same than orderNumber in table orders?
LEFT JOIN orderdetails as OD on OD.orderLineNumber = O.orderNumber 
LEFT JOIN products as P on P.productCode = OD.productCode
-- The result will be order by customerNumber, of for each customerNumber by orderDate
ORDER BY C.customerNumber, O.orderDate
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks that helped get me going. In the end, I used something like this:


SELECT 
    *
FROM
    orders
        CROSS JOIN
    orderdetails
  CROSS JOIN
 products 
WHERE
    customerNumber and  orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber and  orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode
    ORDER BY orders.orderDate;